# Laravel login timing out

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

After starting up a new Laravel project, creating the UI with bootstrap, and setting up the auth controllers using:
`php artisan make:auth` I ran the database migration and seeded a user which came across fine in the remote database. I tried an initial login at the `/login` and received the error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = redacted@gmail.com limit 1)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
```

I have not modified any files away from the defaults that artisan created. I have however noticed the primary culprit seems to be the email itself is not a string, running the query in MySQL throws the same type of syntax error which i'm assuming is the issue. I'm just not sure ( lacking enough knowledge of Laravel ) to be able to further diagnose.

If more information is required, i'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: The exception message usually replaces the placeholders with their values meaning the actual query you see in the error is not really what's executed. The error here is a timeout which probably means the database server might be unreachable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

*add this in your config folder databse.php file*

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')
```

and first you try

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: Added and restarted the application. No change at all, same error.

Comment: I had unfortunately added this already and cleared the caches, which did not provide any relief. Since running the query in MySQL directly threw an error, i'm convinced it's an issue in which the way the query does not wrap the email as a string. If that makes sense.

Comment: It's the same error as originally posted. When i run that query directly in MySQL i get : ````Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '@gmail.com limit 1' at line 1````. If i convert the email to a string, the query runs just fine: ````select * from `users` where `email` = 'redacted@gmail.com' limit 1````

Comment: again run php artisan migrate

Comment: I've run `php artisan migrate`, it's recreated the tables. I've seeded in a single user. The problem is still that when `Auth` runs the query to select the user the ````email = email@email.com```` is failing because the email is not a string, causing a mysql error.

Comment: change your database folder users table  email  like     `$table->string('email')->unique();`

Comment: That's exactly what it is already. Is there somewhere to define MySQL variables to be strings when making queries ?

Comment: So i solved the issue. It was a combination of a few things i believe. A few of them maybe have been cleared up with your help, but the primary issue was the request was the connection to the database was being blocked from the application. I cleared up a few items block the request and it seems to be working now. I'll upvote for you assistance and guidance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

in databse.php file

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')
```

```
php artisan config:cache
```